# Xbox One Port Forward for Remote SmartGlass

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-smartglass

I'm trying to use SmartGlass for my Xbox One from outside my home network. I know this isn't quite the intended functionality but it should be possible with the right port forwarding.

Does anyone know the ports that need to be forwarded for this to be possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible as there's no way (that I can see from the menus) to get the XB1's actual IP. You can only get its IP on the network (example: 192.168.1.XXX). Maybe ask this question on SuperUser? They would probably be a better help.

Comment: I would try using a VPN to verify that it would even be usable. Next I would set my Xbox in the DMZ and test then.

Answer (score -1):

SmartGlas does not require port forwarding to my knowledge as it should work using HTTP which, ideally, should already be correctly forwarded by your router. However, specific games require specific ports to use SmartGlass as companion applications. You should check these game's pages for more information.

All in all, there is a bigger flaw in your plan. SmartGlass has been designed to work on LAN, not WAN. Your IP is likely not static making it pain to keep track of it. And even if you could track it, the IP might not be public and your ISP may have therefore made it impossible for you to remotely connect to your LAN. I believe your best bet is to try and establish a Virtual Private Network. Still, I think the endeavour is highly doubtful.

What would you like to use this for if I may inquire? There might be an easier way to accomplish it.